# How can I access hidden plank settings?

Tags: settings, plank

i don't see any way to change settings for Plank, icon size... Before it was possible by .config,  or Elementary Tweaks.

Answer (score 6):

You can still change them - on any icon on Plank, just do CTRL+RightClick, then proceed to "Preferences"

Answer (score 4):

Its hard to rightclick to get the preference. You can do it from the command line

```
plank --preferences
```

Comment: I can confirm that doing a ctrl-right click on Plank will bring up its menu.