# Hiding running apps in Plank in Juno

Tags: plank

There used to be a setting in Plank settings to hide the unpinned apps, super useful. I cannot find it any more.
Has it been moved in Juno, or removed?
Thanks a lot!

Edit: including a screenshot of my settings page for the dock. Most settings are gone in this release and it makes me a little frustrated.
[image]

The reason why I'd hide some apps is to have things like widgets stay on the desktop, without appearing in the Plank. In the attached screenshot, see the bottom right end of the Plank: three extra icons from the widgets that I use at the moment.
[image]

Comment: I never understood that option, it's there, see my answer. But how is that useful?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access hidden plank settings?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/how-can-i-access-hidden-plank-settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question the OP is referring to the *Desktop>Dock* settings, which do not include what is asked (did they ever?).

The option is accessible under the **Plank preferences**, which are independent from the system settings. Plank preferences are accessible in different ways:

- press Ctrl-key and right-click Plank dock, then select "Preferences"

or

- run `plank --preferences` in terminal.

Therefore this question might even be a duplicate of [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7531/170).

Un-check "Show unpinned".

[image]

---

Comment: I've edited my original post please see some clarification. Thank you for replying!

Comment: @DrAcid - the settings that you have posted in the question as image are under *settings - desktop*. My answer is referring to the Plank settings, accessible as indicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification!
It's surprising why they ever split the settings in the firstplace.

Comment: @DrAcid - Plank is a very light program that is in no way dependent upon the elementary system, but can be easily installed on any Linux. elementary tries to reduce user intervention and access to settings, it's their hallmark, which I find annoying and ridiculous: mimicking apple! If they wanted the user to be that passive they should offer in exchange something more than mimicry, maybe start manufacturing computers that could make one forget the software limitations:)